# AVfoundation AudioPlayer not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, audio, avfoundation

I am trying to play a sound on button click using the AVFoundation framework. Previously, i used audio toolbox however when i use the audioplayer nothing comes out. What is weird is that when i test it on my phone and i press the button, the volume controls aren't the normal ringer volume controls. This suggests that it should be playing but i can't hear anything, on my phone or the simulator. I have used different files, created new project changed the code, nothing has helped.

Here's the code in .h:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>

- (IBAction)test;
```

Here's the code in .m:

```
- (IBAction)test {
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
theAudio.delegate = self;
[theAudio play];
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if `theAudio` is nil?

Comment: @sergio how do I do this?

Comment: You've declared that you'll implement the `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` did you in fact do this? No code here for it.  However, I concur with previous comments.  Most likely `path` is `nil` and `[theAudio play]` is then a no-op.

Comment: @Marko ok thanks! what code would i need to put in and where? sorry i'm not the best at it yet.

Comment: @rblue36: put a `NSlog(@"theAudio address: %x", (long)theAudio);` right after initializing `theAudio`...

Comment: btw, you could also pass a `NSError` in when calling `initWithContentsOfURL` so you know if something goes wrong...

Comment: @sergio how do i do that, never done NSLog before

Comment: @rblue: copy from `NSLog` up to the final `;` and paste it before `theAudio.delegate = self;`

Comment: @sergio thanks for the simplicity! it gives an apple mach-o error

Answer (score 0):

can you do this before you play the sound i think you might have the wrong category:

```
AudioSessionInitialize (NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,sizeof (sessionCategory),&sessionCategory); 
AudioSessionSetActive(true);
```

Comment: this?                                                             - (IBAction)test {
    AudioSessionInitialize (NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
    AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,sizeof (sessionCategory),&sessionCategory);
    AudioSessionSetActive(true);
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"hagay" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];
}

Comment: Whilst definitely needed for non-trivial uses of audio, the default does enabled audio output.